# Stack Overflow's snippet giving wrong results

Tags: support, stack-snippets

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885327/2019247). Run the snippet and observe the results in snippet's console. Now, find the same code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4ut3cnz/), run it, and observe the results in your browser's console.

I can't understand why the code doesn't work in Stack Overflow's snippet, but works fine in JSFiddle?

This only happens if I have a declaration `var status = ...` in my code. If I change it to `let status = ...`, the problem goes away.

Comment: So, basically, how you are using JSFiddle is hiding a bug in your code, due to the default JSFiddle configuration masking the issue. In reality, it is JSFiddle that is giving the wrong results, not the Stack Overflow snippet.

Comment: @31piy, I agree that snippets should not conflict with variables defined by SO. However, that's not the case here. You are conflicting with a global variable that exists on every single page, `window.status` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status)), it's not an SO defined property. SO should *not* protect you from conflicts with base `window` properties. Doing so would result in masking errors, making it impossible to reproduce some issues.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because the variable name is `status`. It conflicts with the global `window.status` variable. When you rename `status` to e.g. `foo`, it works.

```js
console.log(status); // <empty string>
var status = {
  'To Do': 1,
  'Received': 2,
  'In Progress': 3,
  'Rejected': 4,
  'Verify': 5, 
  'Live': 6
};
console.log(status); // [object Object]
console.log(foo); // undefined
var foo = {
  'To Do': 1,
  'Received': 2,
  'In Progress': 3,
  'Rejected': 4,
  'Verify': 5, 
  'Live': 6
};
console.log(foo);
// { To Do: 1, Received: 2, In Progress: 3, Rejected: 4, Verify: 5, Live: 6 }
```

Comment: ... or we can declare it using `let`. This was the resolution which was suggested, and I did the same.

Comment: @31piy or a better name of `statuses`?

Comment: @31piy that works too, but be aware of [browser compatibility](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=let) if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: Encapsulation would work too, and is always a good idea. But yeah, a const declaration would be appropriate there.

Comment: [Grundy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360903/621962) explains why it seems to work, unaltered, on jsfiddle and not in snippets.

Answer (score 10):

A bit explanation: why this works on JSFiddle even with `var`.

By default, jsfiddle has next setting:

*Load Type: OnLoad*

[image]

and this generates next code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

    window.onload=function(){
    var status = {
      'To Do': 1,
      'Received': 2,
      'In Progress': 3,
      'Rejected': 4,
      'Verify': 5,
      'Live': 6
    };

    var data = [{
        userName: "One",
        status: "Live"
      },
      {
        userName: "Two",
        status: "Rejected"
      },
      {
        userName: "Three",
        status: "To Do"
      },
      {
        userName: "Four",
        status: "Verify"
      },
      {
        userName: "Five",
        status: "Received"
      },
      {
        userName: "Six",
        status: "In Progress"
      }
    ];

    data = data.sort((a, b) => status[a.status] - status[b.status]);
    console.log(data);
    }//]]> 

</script>
```

As you can see, `status` in this case is a local variable, instead property of global object.

If change this settings to one of this:

```
No wrap - in head
No wrap - in body
```

You get same behavior as in snippet before.

BTW, code rendered in snippet same as for settings `No wrap - in body`